# Voltage Rating of Differential Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

If I hook up a 25v-rated operational amplifier in a differential configuration, with a +/- 2.5v (5v) supply, can I measure signals 100 volts above the negative supply, so long as the difference between the two inputs is within it's rating?

Comment: What specific diff-amp are you looking at? Can you draw as a schematic of your intended structure around the amp?

Comment: @user2943160 I don't have an exact structure in mind, I just want to know what the voltage rating of an amplifier really means in the differential configuration.

Comment: Read the datasheet, see the absolute maximum limits and recommended operating conditions, do the circuit analysis to ensure that you remain within those limits based on your Vcc/Vee setup. You'll probably need a fairly high impedance from your +100V signal to your amplifier.

Comment: The number you are looking for is called the "common mode voltage". In general, you will not be able to use inputs outside your power supply voltage range.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the input common mode voltage rating is not exceeded, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

> , can I measure signals 100 volts above the negative supply?

Never directly.  But you can attenuate /25 and bias to stay inside the IC’s specs with gain of 25.